# Gradle: How to let product flavors inherit from src/main except for one

Tags: android, inheritance, gradle, android-productflavors

I want to use product flavors for my android apps since it seems like a big advantage. 
However there is one thing I don't get solved:

Lets say, I have a project *Planets* `com.example.planets` and I want to build an app for every planet:

```
productFlavors {
    mercury {
        applicationId "com.example.planets.mercury"
    }
    venus {
        applicationId "com.example.planets.venus"
    }
    ...
}
```

A lot of code is shared and therefore put in the `src/main` folder.

I also want to use the same `MainActivity` in every app **except for the earth app** as it differs in this app. How can I achieve that without copying the non-earth-version in every other folder?

I tried to "override" the `MainActivity` I mentioned above folder but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a file structure like this

```
    .
└── src
    ├── earth
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── app
    │                   ├── MainActivity.java // extends Activity + your code
    │                   └── SomeClass.java
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── app
    │                   ├── MainBaseActivity.java // extends Activity + your code
    │                   └── SomeClass.java
    ├── mercury
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── app
    │                   ├── MainActivity.java // extends MainBaseActivity + empty body
    │                   └── SomeClass.java
    └── venus
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── app
    │                   ├── MainActivity.java // extends MainBaseActivity + empty body
    │                   └── SomeClass.java
```

Where `SomeClass.java` represents all your common classes and codes
mercury and venus will use the `MainActivity`from "main", while earth has it's own specified.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed folder tree, but I always end up having a `Error:(13, 8) error: duplicate class: com.example.planets.MainActivity` when I run the earth app. Did it work for you? How did you resolve the "duplicate class" problem?

Comment: I haven't faced that problem. And yes I have made real apps with this kind of structure. 

Still a workaround I can suggest is, make a MainBaseActivity in main flavor, and extend that 
i.e. 
`MainActivity extends MainBaseActivity { /* empty body */ }`
 in all the flavors that you want unchanged. 
In earth, just go with 

`MainActivity extends Activity {/* your code here*/}`

Comment: I have updated my file tree to show what exactly I mean

Comment: If `SomeClass` represents common code, it's wrong to duplicate it in all the product flavors. There should just be one single copy under `src/main/java`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can put non-earth version inside the `src/main` directory and add earth-related `MainActivity` inside the source directory of `earth` flavour. That way, default version of `MainActivity` will be used by all flavours other than `earth`.

Comment: This is what I want, but when I try it that way, it leads to `Error:(13, 8) error: duplicate class: com.example.planets.MainActivity` when I run the earth app.